# Does the EVM revert if a call is attempted to an address that doesn't have code?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, evm, opcode, code

The following code would revert in high-level Solidity if the provided `addr` is an EOA or a contract that does not implement `MyInterface`:

```
interface MyInterface {
    function myFunction() external;
}

function foo(address addr) {
    MyInterface(addr).myFunction();
}
```

But what if we used a low-level call instead? My understanding is that in that case, the call would be successful. But why is that? Can someone point me to a resource in the EVM spec where this behavior is documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to non-contract addresses (that is, EOAs or inactive accounts) always set the success flag to true and leave the return data field empty, so the right question isnt "Why lows level calls to EOAs don't revert", but rather "Why high level calls to EOAs revert?".

And the reason why `MyInterface(addr).myFunction();` reverts is because the compiler adds a check to `addr`'s `EXTCODESIZE` before the call is made when you call through an interface

Comment: *Can someone point me to a resource in the EVM spec where this behavior is documented?*
Can you add a resource link to this question? @Foxxxey

Comment: I'm not sure it's explicitely specified in the yellow paper or another related ressource (and frankly, don't wanna check ^^') but the idea is that trying to read the code stored at a non-contract address returns 0, which is the STOP opcode, which just sucessfully returns to the previous execution context without doing anything else

Answer (score 1):

A call, any call, has a caller, can have a value and can have some data. The value can be zero, the data can be empty, doesn't matter. By default as explained in the chosen answer, all calls are valid.

Now if a call is received by a smart contract, there are multiple possible scenarios:

1. The message data is empty: The execution of the transaction continues at the `receive()` function or the `fallback()` function if the former is not implemented. If neither of them is available, the transaction will revert.
2. The call has data: the contract will look at the 4 first bytes and see if it matches one of the registered function selectors (functions marked as `public` or `external`. If it finds a match, the transaction execution will continue at that function's location in the bytecode, if not, same as for case (1): it will look for the `fallback` or revert.
3. The message data's first 4 bytes correspond to a function selector that exists on the receiving contract: the transaction's execution will continue by jumping to that part in the contract's code that contains the recognized function selector.

   3a. If the message also had value and the function wasn't marked as `payable` in the solidity code, the function will revert because the Solidity compiler adds that condition explicitly